# If it's not really spam, don't flag it as such!

Tags: discussion

I've only seen one such flag in recent times but it reminded me to remind those unfamiliar with the Stack Exchange model - to be careful with your flags!

Spam/Offensive flags will obviously be handled by mods, so we will be able to prevent any serious fallout, but remember not to flag something as spam or offensive when it is really harmless (such as a user suggesting to use another software rather than the one in question).

**If you need to know more, read this:**
[What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work)